# How to send Ether Using Web3 and Gas Charges are Paid from Another Address?

Tags: web3js, ether

I know using this for send Ether (web3):

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: 'Address A',
    to: 'Address B',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

I'm trying to send ether from address A to address B, then the gas fee is paid by address C for the transaction. Does anyone know about that?

Comment: It is not possible with normal transactions. There are services like tornado.cash that allows deposits by the sender (A) then the recipient (B) can withdraw using a relayer (C).

Comment: @goodvibration ,it looks like it uses a smart contract, that maybe I can use as a last alternative. Do you know the information, if I only use web3?

Comment: The answer says `it's not possible for another one user other than the user originating the transaction to pay for the gas`, what more information do you need?

Comment: ah ok I see. I just found out that and am still just learning this.